# Whois gem not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whois, whois-ruby

```
class DomaincheckerController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def store
    r =Whois.whois(secure_params['domain'])
    render :text => "#{r}"
  end

  private
  def secure_params
    params.require(:whois).permit(:domain)
  end


end
```

This is my domainchecker controller. The index method renders a form. After submitting the form it goes to store method. Here I am trying to use the `whois`   gem. I have installed whois gem by running `gem install whois`. But I am getting this error.

```
uninitialized constant DomaincheckerController::Whois
```

Comment: Standard question in those cases: have you restarted the server after installing a gem?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, I have restarted niginx as well as unicorn too

Comment: How did you restarted unicorn? USR2? You need to do hard restart. No need to reboot nginx.

Comment: @BroiSatse, I thought I restarted unicorn.

I did `service unicorn_fuitter stop` and then ran `service unicorn_fuitter start` . But even when I did `service unicorn_fuitter stop` my app was still running.

Comment: Your etc script might be incorrect. Try restarting it manually using `kill --QUIT`

Comment: @BroiSatse kill --QUIT, gave me an error

`-bash: kill: -QUIT: invalid signal specification`

Comment: How did you install the gem?

Comment: @RajShakya - Have you give it a pid of your unicorn service?

Comment: ok, i have done hard restart and still it is showing me the `uninitialized constant DomaincheckerController::Whois ` err

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, I did `gem install whois`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you installed the gem directly and not using `bundler`, therefore the Rails app can't find the dependency.

In order to install a gem in a Rails project you need to edit the `Gemfile` file and add the gem there. Once added, run

```
$ bundle
```

in order to install the dependency. Check the [documentation about the Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html).